# What's the point of the javascript navigator.javaEnabled function?

Tags: javascript-framework, navigator

The navigator object has a javaEnabled function that indicates if the browser has javascript support. 
This seems to be a little odd:

- If JS is indeed enabled the function
  will return true, well obviously.
- If JS is disabled it will return
  <*nothing*> since it is never run,
  javaScript is disabled.

I must be missing something here, or is it really that useless this function?

Answer (score 10):

`java`!= `javaScript`

`navigator.javaEnabled` checks for the presence of *Java*, not JavaScript.

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_nav_javaenabled.asp)

This must be a relic from the olden days when Java applets were going to be the future of the web...

Comment: "olden days when Java applets were going to be the future of the web", That is the point. It should be deprecated!

Answer (score 3):

You missed the fact that it's **`java`**`Enabled` not `javascriptEnabled`.

> navigator.javaEnabled: Indicates whether the host browser is Java-enabled or not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.navigator