# Javascript detection not working anymore

Tags: javascript, wicket

After this weekend my Wicket application cannot correctly detect javascript anymore. It doesn't work on my webhoster, on my local machine and I tested it also on another computer.

My detection script:

```
WebClientInfo clientInfo = (WebClientInfo)WebSession.get().getClientInfo();
    if(!clientInfo.getProperties().isJavaEnabled()){
        System.out.println("not enabled!");
        WebSession.get().setClientInfo(null);
    }
```

plus this in the application class:

```
getRequestCycleSettings().setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo(true);
```

I also created a wicket app from scratch, same result, no javascript detection.

While writing this I checked it in the Internet Explorer. Works fine with IE 8 + 9. Doesn't work with FF 11.0. Wicket version is 1.5.5.

Anyone can confirm this behavior? (possible JIRA-worthy...)

**UPDATE:** I found the cause of this behavior. `isJavaEnabled` checks if Java (not Javascript) is enabled. Firefox (silently) blocked the Java plugin on April 2nd, therefore no javaEnabled property set: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/p80. Cumbersome.

Comment: What have changed in your app since this weekend ? There are no changes in Wicket itself in this area since a long time.

Comment: That's the funny thing, I changed nothing, wasn't around the whole weekend. Not my webapp, not my wicket version, not my browser, hoster changed nothing (afaik but I got the same problem on my local computer and I changed nothing). Probably some weird easter egg joke...

Comment: Maybe an update of Firefox/Chrome disabled the support of Java (not JavaScript at the client side). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897333/whats-the-point-of-the-javascript-navigator-javaenabled-function

Comment: That was my assumption too, but 11.0 is out since March 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely this never worked, and the fact that it seemed to was dumb luck.

Looking at the javadocs for [ClientProperties.isJavaEnabled()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/ClientProperties.html#isJavaEnabled%28%29), it returns the client's `navigator.javaEnabled` property, which reflects whether **Java** is enabled, not **JavaScript**.

Java != JavaScript.

Comment: I thought it was just poor naming, thanks. Several guides found on the internet use this method for javascript detection. I tested it with the NoScript-addon and it worked correctly but now that you mentioned it, NoScript also blocks Java-Applets, therefore setting navigator.javaEnabled to false. I stick to the old and simple noscript-tags then (or are there "better" ways to do this?).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the 'user agent' string:

```
public boolean javascriptSupported() {
    WebRequest webRequest = (WebRequest) getRequest();
    String userAgent = webRequest.getHeader("User-Agent");
    if (userAgent == null || userAgent.startsWith("Googlebot")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have used this to fallback on `AjaxLazyLoadPanel` for search engines, although you would need to expand on the list of user-agents above.

There is also `WebRequest.isAjax()`, which might be useful too, as it is used to determine the `RedirectPolicy` used, and thus, the behaviour of Wicket when Javascript is not present.